# How to Replace Inputted Text with Preset Text c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to create a Windows Form Application in Visual Studio. What I am trying to do is when the user types something in the RichTextBox it deletes what you type and replaces it with a preset letter. What I have so far is:

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string text = richTextBox1.Text;
    richTextBox1.Text = text.Remove(text.Length - 1, 1);
}
```

So when you type one letter it erases it. What I want after that is it adds one letter of a preset text. So let's say that you have the text `This is a test text that is reasonably long`. When the user types 'A', the letter 'T' appears instead. When the user types another letter, the next letter 'h' appears instead, and so forth until the full text `This is a test text that is reasonably long` is shown, and then you cannot type any more.

Here is more code if required:

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
}

private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate("www.google.com");
}

private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string text = richTextBox1.Text;
    richTextBox1.Text = text.Remove(text.Length - 1, 1);
}
```

Comment: richTextBox1.Text = text.Substring(0, richTextBox1.Length);  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to this.

```
public string longText = "This is a test text that is reasonably long";
private void RichTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    // I don't know if the user can press enter 
    // and give you an empty string so this checks that 
    // and that richTextBox1.Text is not greater than the 
    // text you want replace with, in this case longText
    if (richTextBox1.Text.Length <= longText.Length && richTextBox1.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        string text = richTextBox1.Text;
        // removes the last character, Remove returns 
        // a new string so you have to save it somewhere
        text = richTextBox1.Text.Remove(text.Length - 1, 1);
        // here you add the character you want to replace
        text += longText[richTextBox1.Text.Length - 1];
        richTextBox1.Text = text;
    }
    else if (richTextBox1.Text.Length > longText.Length)
    {
        // this case is when the user wants to add another 
        // character but the whole text it's been already replaced
        richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Remove(richTextBox1.Text.Length - 1, 1);
        }
    }
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.

Comment: I seem to have gotten an error on the line `if (enrichedText.Length <= longText.Length)`, saying that "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'" and "enrichedText was null". Is there something I am missing from your answer?

Comment: Sorry @MainframeHacker, I did something with my VS and I was unable to test that. I already edited the answer and gave a better one, I think hehe. Regards!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what happened, but it seems that all this does is take the text that the user types and puts it backwards, so I typed "What is going on?" and I got "?no gniog si tahW" And the first letter "W" sometimes changes to another letter.

Comment: I don't know how is that possible, could you share more of your code, please? I assume that richTextBox1 is where the user enters the text and every time that hits a key it triggers RichTextBox1_TextChanged(...)

Comment: There isn't really that much else in the code. All there is, is the richTextBox1 and a simple webBrowser. I can remove the webBrowser if necessary, but I didn't think that it would create any issues. I added some more of the code if necessary.